# Intersection points of plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $F,G\in\Bbb{C}[X,Y,Z]$ be coprime homogeneous polynomials of degrees $m$ and $n$ respectively that do not have multiple factors. By Bezout's Theorem, the number of intersection points of plane curves
$\{F=0\}$ and $\{G=0\}$ in $\Bbb{CP}^2$ is $mn$ once counted with appropriate multiplicities. Is there a characterization of multisets of size $mn$ of points of $\Bbb{CP}^2$ that can be realized as such an intersection? I imagine not every subset is realizable because requiring a polynomial to vanish at a point of the projective plane is a linear equation in the space of polynomials; so if $m<n$, the number of linear conditions that vanishing at $mn$ points of $\Bbb{CP}^2$ imposes on a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m$ is larger than the dimension of the corresponding polynomial space.

Update: I rephrase my question following Zach Teitler's comment: Is there a characterization of zero-dimensional subschemes of length $mn$ of the projective plane that are complete intersections?

Comment: These are called complete intersections. You are asking for a characterization of complete intersections among schemes (not multisets) of length $mn$.

Comment: A characteriztion: your set lives on a curve $C$ of degree $m$; assuming for simplicity that $C$ is smooth, the corresponding divisor on $C$ belongs to the linear system $\lvert \mathscr{O}_{C}(n)\rvert$. You won't find anything simpler.

Comment: The intersections satisfy the Cayley-Bacharach property. I don't remember if that's also a sufficient condition.